# How to use Backbone.js for single page websites in a certain way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, backbone.js

Essentially, I want to create a personal website that functions like this one:

https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Jade

Whereby it's contained within one HTML page and clicking on a nav item will only load the required information.

Looking at the javascript code I believe the developer is using Backbone.js and Handlebars.js. I think they used PHP for the backend.

There is a key functionality that I'm after that is within this site. Essentially, when you are at the aforementioned directory, and then you change to https://sublime.wbond.net/docs, there will be an AJAX request for only the HTML that's needed and then it is appended to the current page.

Having written a simple backbone app by following a tutorial, it seems it's done differently. Hosting the app using node, it will load all of the content. When you go to another directory, it still loads all the content and then backbone will append the right piece based on the URL. I can see this being useful for certain kinds of apps, but I don't want that functionality. I looked into it more and I thought about using the fetch() functionality in backbone, but I'm not too sure he's using that either.

It appears like he's doing something like Rendr by Airbnb. I can't really use that because there the documentation is not sufficient right now.

It looks like when you call a page it just gives you the HTML all ready without the need to compile it locally. Is there something I'm missing here in terms of utilizing backbone or is this just some tool he's made to handle this?

Comment: Backbone routers let you do this. You need to tell it to use pushState though. http://backbonejs.org/#Router

Answer (score 0):

If you are not afraid spending hours in front of videos, those [excellent screencasts](http://www.backbonerails.com/series/engineering_single_page_apps) could get you started : the guy explains how to build a Single-Page app using Backbone and Marionette, from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

This web site is not using Backbone, and the solution he uses is a mixte of full html page load and JSon call, look at this links :

https://sublime.wbond.net/browse.json

https://sublime.wbond.net/search.json

https://sublime.wbond.net/docs.html

https://sublime.wbond.net/news.html

https://sublime.wbond.net/stats.json

Comment: Yes, I observed this while looking at the site. If you look in app.js however, you'll see references to Backbone and Handlebars, which is why I think he's using them, even though it is not explicitly shown to include them.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to have the same behavior as wbond.net will be to change the way you render the page on the backend. You need to check if request is XHR and render only content, without layout. On the frontend you need to bind click event to each links which will send AJAX request on binded URL and put whole response in the page content area (jQuery's $.get() method).

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm going to have to do a check to see if XHR then send different code within node, which is pretty easy.